# how to check if all elements of array are nil and returns true or false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 hashes like below:

A:

```
{"items"=>[
{"id"=>"1582047441225902782_5735285038", "location"=>{"name"=>"city, country"}}, 
{"id"=>"1582045444762412016_5735285038", "location"=>{"name"=>"city, country"}}, 
{"id"=>"1579295851704320004_5735285038", "location"=>{"name"=>"city, country"}}
]
}
```

B:

```
{"items"=>[
{"id"=>"1291968139634730329_3268566686", "location"=>nil}, 
{"id"=>"1289715984018418358_3268566686", "location"=>nil}, 
{"id"=>"1265437960134352110_3268566686", "location"=>nil}, 
{"id"=>"1265436628937759921_3268566686", "location"=>nil}, 
{"id"=>"1265435354792090734_3268566686", "location"=>nil}, 
{"id"=>"1263837986099453523_3268566686", "location"=>nil}, 
{"id"=>"1263836777863077412_3268566686", "location"=>nil}, 
{"id"=>"1263835770617748979_3268566686", "location"=>nil}, 
{"id"=>"1263058120273977093_3268566686", "location"=>nil}, 
{"id"=>"1263049902374149585_3268566686", "location"=>nil}
]
}
```

What I need to see if my all locations are nil, means not even a single location have value in it so array should return false.

And if a single element is having location value it should return true that means all locations are nil but few or one have value as well.

I am trying like:

```
ary['items'].map {|e| puts e['location']['name'].nil?}
```

but it says:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `all?` method.

```
ary["items"].all? { |item| item["location"].nil? }
```

Comment: `items = ary["items"]` should fix it

Answer (score 1):

To check if at least one location is not `nil`, using a one liner:

```
ary['items'].any? { |item| !item['location'].nil? }
```

Comment: it says `TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer`

Comment: yeah I was just a generic array, I edited the solution to reflect your structure